# Stop sending email from journey when lead converted into account and contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a journey on Lead creation, and I have a set of emails can say for 15 days by waiting one-day interval for each email.

But In between these intervals, the lead converted into contact, opportunity, and Account, I want to stop the lead journey so stop sending the email, immediately when it is converted.

I have one separate journey for contact, As lead converted into contact they start sending the contact journey emails, not the lead journey emails.

I am using Isconverted=false and ISConverted=True in the decision split, but it is not stopping the sending out lead emails when it got converted into contact.

Any suggestion , Is it poosible to implement.

Comment: Hi Manish, for those kind of journeys I use decision splits before every email send activity, and check contact data to see if the lead has been converted, and if yes, add the lead to a separate campaign in sales cloud, which will put them in a journey for contacts. But I can see how this would be painful solution if you have a journey with 15 emails.

Comment: @zuzannamj, actually we do not have any campaign associated , directly bringing leads data in journey on lead creation, then in between set of email , at any instance id lead converted into account and contact , then these subscriber exits the lead journey .

Comment: Is there any way where i can directly use isconverted filed in the decision split to check ,

Comment: You should be able to check whether the lead has been converted or not, and then direct the converted leads onto a path where they don’t get any more emails. Make sure you are using contact data, not journey data for that

Comment: Actually , I created DE and pulling data from synchronized DE and then , using data designer , created relationship between data extensions and the by using decision split , I am checking isconverted=false or not ,SO it this right approach I am following or you mean to say different use case by contact data?